# Getting the correct headers automatically given a filetype in PHP

Tags: php, header, content-type

Sorry - looks like this is a duplicate of: [How to get the content-type of a file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php)

---

A few times I've run into situations where I'd like to be able to include a file using PHP, and depending on the included filetype, output the appropriate headers. In the past I've just done this manually by switch/casing the extension type with the appropriate content-type headers.

However what I'm wondering now is if there's a function like

```
get_header($filename)
```

or maybe

```
get_contenttype($extension)
```

For example if I wanted to route all requests for media through a php file, I could use that function to output the correct headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`finfo_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) might help. There some more info [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php).