# PHP files type checking

Tags: php

Some weird case when I tried a simple php code to check the file type and it couldn't pass through. Any mistake from the below code ? Thanks in advance.

```
if(($_FILES["file"]["type"]!="image/jpeg")||
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"]!="image/gif")||
            ($_FILES["file"]["type"]!="image/png")){
            echo "File must be in format of jpeg,gif or png.";
        }
```

Comment: You have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your html form right?
If yes and you can print_r $_FILES then look for answer what @deceze gave.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Not a JPEG", "not a GIF", "not a PNG"*. At least two of these conditions *have* to be `true`. Since you're using `||`, if *any* of these is `true`, the whole `if` condition is `true`.

You're looking for *"is not JPEG **and** is not GIF **and** is not PNG"*.

Apart from that, you can use the much more succinct form:

```
!in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], array('image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png'))
```

Also, the `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is user supplied information which you shouldn't trust. You should try to figure out the MIME type yourself from the file itself. For example, see [How to get the content-type of a file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

mime_content_type('php.gif') will output image/gif

Comment: thanks for remind me about the type being check using mime as deceze mention this too. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditionals are wrong, you want "&&" rather than "||". Also, `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is the type as reported by the browser, so it may well be incorrect or missing. Have you tried logging it to see what exactly the browser is sending?

You'd be much better served by using [FileInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.fileinfo.php) or the like to check the type, or seeing if [GD](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) or another image processing extension accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer [getimagesize()](http://de3.php.net/getimagesize) to avoid problems with the mime-types, especially of JPEGs, where are a lot of mime-types are possible.(As Anomie wrote `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` is the type as reported by the browser).

Try it, take some exotic filetype and give it an extension like .gif or .jpg.

`$_FILES["file"]["type"]` will report something like 'image.gif' or 'image.jpeg', but getimagesize() will return `false`, because it detects that the file is not an image.

This can be used to upload e.g. PHP-scripts onto the server.

Also note: never trust any uploaded file, images may be correct but can also contain PHP-code inside comments. So be sure that those images never can be included by any PHP-script on your server.(additionally you could check the image for PHP-code)