# Wrong Mime-type in uploaded file

Tags: php, firefox, file-upload, mime-types

I have form for file uploading in my website that i check mime-type of uploaded file to allow or refuse uploading it. It worked well until I've upgraded my firefox to 3.6.11 (in ubuntu). But now uploading Doc files is not possible. I checked the mime-type of file but it was 'application/x-php' instead of 'application/vnd.ms-word' or other msword mime-types.

I use

```
echo $_FILES[$fileName]['type'];
```

to see the mime-type. I upload the same file from firefox 8 and firefox 3.6 and the output of above code was:

```
FireFox 8: application/vnd.ms-word
FireFox 3.6: application/x-php
```

Is it a bug of firefox or I have to change my codes?

I use PHP.

Comment: *How* are you checking the MIME type?

Comment: I have written a function,but for debugging I just echo $_FILES[$fileName]['type']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_FILES[...]['type']` is just arbitrary, user supplied, best-guess, unreliable (as you see) information supplied by the client which may or may not have anything to do with the actual file. **Never use it.**

Try to detect the MIME type yourself on the server. For example techniques, see [How to get the content-type of a file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php).

Comment: Oh yes, i was uploading a PNG file erroneously named *.jpg and `$_FILES[...]['type']` was wrongly reporting `image/jpeg`.