# How to upload .mp3 file in php only after validation,my .wav file gets uploaded easily

Tags: php

```
if ((($_FILES["myfile"]["type"] == "audio/mp3") ||
     ($_FILES["myfile"]["type"] == "audio/wav")) &&
    ($_FILES["myfile"]["size"] < 20000000)) 
{
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path) )
    {
        $result1=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: use this mime for mp3: audio/mpeg

Comment: The ["type"] value is provided by the browser: it could be forged, wrong, or even missing. DO NOT TRUST IT!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just `print $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];`  for real mp3 file then copy the value and use it instead of audio/mp3 because MIME type of mp3 will not be 'audio/mp3', i think its `audio/mpeg`

Please check this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php) also, because its not recommended to depend on `$_FILES["myfile"]["type"]` that send by browser.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

Check the size of your `.mp3` file. 
Check the file type of your `.mp3` if it is actually `audio/mp3`. Try `print_r($_FILES);`.

```
$type = $_FILES["myfile"]["type"];
$size = $_FILES["myfile"]["size"];

if( ( ($type == "audio/mp3") || ($type == "audio/wav") ) && ($size < 20000000)) {
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path) ) {
        $result1=1;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for no explaining it clearly,but what i actually mean was i want to upload only .wav & .mp3 file,using the code above which i gave,.wav files gets esaily uploaded but .mp3 file dont get uploaded..

Answer (score 0):

You can check by evaluating the extension of the uploaded file or if you want to check file level then you can one of the pear packages https://pear.php.net/package/MP3_ID