# application/msword instead of application/vnd.ms-excel

Tags: php, excel, mime-types

Both functions (mime_content_type and finfo_file) returns wrong mime type (application/msword) of my xls file.
Question is why?

This tool http://mime.ritey.com/ returns proper mime type - application/vnd.ms-excel

I use script for attachment management for webmail and it has to be very universal. How to fix problem?

Comment: Use an up-to-date mime magic file. And are you sure that the files really are the type that they claim to be?

Comment: Note that the link you've posted uses the content type passed to the upload by the browser, which is easily fooled

Comment: this might help.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php