# Getting MimeType from file source in PHP

Tags: php, file, mime-types

So I am working in an api that accepts a base 64 encoded file's contents.  There is an attribute for file type but apparently the client is sending a file that doesn't match the file type.  The file name is irrelevant, they do not send one.

Is there a way to determine the mime type of the file being sent after I decode the file contents?

Comment: What have you tried? http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php ?

Comment: This will not work, right?  I need to get the mime type from the source of the file (the contents) not the file name.

Comment: Right, you may want to find the content-type of the file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php