# PHP text file upload occurs wrong response

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

In codeigniter mime.php,

```
array(
    'hqx'   =>  array('application/mac-binhex40', 'application/mac-binhex', 'application/x-binhex40', 'application/x-mac-binhex40'),
    'cpt'   =>  'application/mac-compactpro',
    'csv'   =>  array('text/x-comma-separated-values', 'text/comma-separated-values', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/x-csv', 'text/x-csv', 'text/csv', 'application/csv', 'application/excel', 'application/vnd.msexcel', 'text/plain'),
    'bin'   =>  array('application/macbinary', 'application/mac-binary', 'application/octet-stream', 'application/x-binary', 'application/x-macbinary'),
    'dms'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'lha'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'lzh'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'exe'   =>  array('application/octet-stream', 'application/x-msdownload'),
    'class' =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'psd'   =>  array('application/x-photoshop', 'image/vnd.adobe.photoshop'),
    'so'    =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'sea'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'dll'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'oda'   =>  'application/oda',
    'pdf'   =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/force-download', 'application/x-download', 'binary/octet-stream'),
    'ai'    =>  array('application/pdf', 'application/postscript'),
    'eps'   =>  'application/postscript',
    'ps'    =>  'application/postscript',
    'smi'   =>  'application/smil',
    'smil'  =>  'application/smil',
    'mif'   =>  'application/vnd.mif',
    'xls'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel', 'application/x-msexcel', 'application/x-ms-excel', 'application/x-excel', 'application/x-dos_ms_excel', 'application/xls', 'application/x-xls', 'application/excel', 'application/download', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword'),
    'ppt'   =>  array('application/powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword'),
    'pptx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation', 'application/x-zip', 'application/zip'),
    'wbxml' =>  'application/wbxml',
    'wmlc'  =>  'application/wmlc',
    'dcr'   =>  'application/x-director',
    'dir'   =>  'application/x-director',
    'dxr'   =>  'application/x-director',
    'dvi'   =>  'application/x-dvi',
    'gtar'  =>  'application/x-gtar',
    'gz'    =>  'application/x-gzip',
    'gzip'  =>  'application/x-gzip',
    'php'   =>  array('application/x-httpd-php', 'application/php', 'application/x-php', 'text/php', 'text/x-php', 'application/x-httpd-php-source'),
    'php4'  =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
    'php3'  =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
    'phtml' =>  'application/x-httpd-php',
    'phps'  =>  'application/x-httpd-php-source',
    'js'    =>  array('application/x-javascript', 'text/plain'),
    'swf'   =>  'application/x-shockwave-flash',
    'sit'   =>  'application/x-stuffit',
    'tar'   =>  'application/x-tar',
    'tgz'   =>  array('application/x-tar', 'application/x-gzip-compressed'),
    'z' =>  'application/x-compress',
    'xhtml' =>  'application/xhtml+xml',
    'xht'   =>  'application/xhtml+xml',
    'zip'   =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/s-compressed', 'multipart/x-zip'),
    'rar'   =>  array('application/x-rar', 'application/rar', 'application/x-rar-compressed'),
    'mid'   =>  'audio/midi',
    'midi'  =>  'audio/midi',
    'mpga'  =>  'audio/mpeg',
    'mp2'   =>  'audio/mpeg',
    'mp3'   =>  array('audio/mpeg', 'audio/mpg', 'audio/mpeg3', 'audio/mp3'),
    'aif'   =>  array('audio/x-aiff', 'audio/aiff'),
    'aiff'  =>  array('audio/x-aiff', 'audio/aiff'),
    'aifc'  =>  'audio/x-aiff',
    'ram'   =>  'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
    'rm'    =>  'audio/x-pn-realaudio',
    'rpm'   =>  'audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin',
    'ra'    =>  'audio/x-realaudio',
    'rv'    =>  'video/vnd.rn-realvideo',
    'wav'   =>  array('audio/x-wav', 'audio/wave', 'audio/wav'),
    'bmp'   =>  array('image/bmp', 'image/x-bmp', 'image/x-bitmap', 'image/x-xbitmap', 'image/x-win-bitmap', 'image/x-windows-bmp', 'image/ms-bmp', 'image/x-ms-bmp', 'application/bmp', 'application/x-bmp', 'application/x-win-bitmap'),
    'gif'   =>  'image/gif',
    'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
    'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
    'jpe'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
    'jp2'   =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'j2k'   =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'jpf'   =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'jpg2'  =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'jpx'   =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'jpm'   =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'mj2'   =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'mjp2'  =>  array('image/jp2', 'video/mj2', 'image/jpx', 'image/jpm'),
    'png'   =>  array('image/png',  'image/x-png'),
    'tiff'  =>  'image/tiff',
    'tif'   =>  'image/tiff',
    'css'   =>  array('text/css', 'text/plain'),
    'html'  =>  array('text/html', 'text/plain'),
    'htm'   =>  array('text/html', 'text/plain'),
    'shtml' =>  array('text/html', 'text/plain'),
    'txt'   =>  'text/plain',
    'text'  =>  array('text/plain', 'application/octet-stream'),
    'log'   =>  array('text/plain', 'text/x-log'),
    'rtx'   =>  'text/richtext',
    'rtf'   =>  'text/rtf',
    'xml'   =>  array('application/xml', 'text/xml', 'text/plain'),
    'xsl'   =>  array('application/xml', 'text/xsl', 'text/xml'),
    'mpeg'  =>  'video/mpeg',
    'mpg'   =>  'video/mpeg',
    'mpe'   =>  'video/mpeg',
    'qt'    =>  'video/quicktime',
    'mov'   =>  'video/quicktime',
    'avi'   =>  array('video/x-msvideo', 'video/msvideo', 'video/avi', 'application/x-troff-msvideo'),
    'movie' =>  'video/x-sgi-movie',
    'doc'   =>  array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office'),
    'docx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip', 'application/msword', 'application/x-zip'),
    'dot'   =>  array('application/msword', 'application/vnd.ms-office'),
    'dotx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', 'application/zip', 'application/msword'),
    'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword', 'application/x-zip'),
    'word'  =>  array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream'),
    'xl'    =>  'application/excel',
    'eml'   =>  'message/rfc822',
    'json'  =>  array('application/json', 'text/json'),
    'pem'   =>  array('application/x-x509-user-cert', 'application/x-pem-file', 'application/octet-stream'),
    'p10'   =>  array('application/x-pkcs10', 'application/pkcs10'),
    'p12'   =>  'application/x-pkcs12',
    'p7a'   =>  'application/x-pkcs7-signature',
    'p7c'   =>  array('application/pkcs7-mime', 'application/x-pkcs7-mime'),
    'p7m'   =>  array('application/pkcs7-mime', 'application/x-pkcs7-mime'),
    'p7r'   =>  'application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp',
    'p7s'   =>  'application/pkcs7-signature',
    'crt'   =>  array('application/x-x509-ca-cert', 'application/x-x509-user-cert', 'application/pkix-cert'),
    'crl'   =>  array('application/pkix-crl', 'application/pkcs-crl'),
    'der'   =>  'application/x-x509-ca-cert',
    'kdb'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'pgp'   =>  'application/pgp',
    'gpg'   =>  'application/gpg-keys',
    'sst'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'csr'   =>  'application/octet-stream',
    'rsa'   =>  'application/x-pkcs7',
    'cer'   =>  array('application/pkix-cert', 'application/x-x509-ca-cert'),
    '3g2'   =>  'video/3gpp2',
    '3gp'   =>  array('video/3gp', 'video/3gpp'),
    'mp4'   =>  'video/mp4',
    'm4a'   =>  'audio/x-m4a',
    'f4v'   =>  array('video/mp4', 'video/x-f4v'),
    'flv'   =>  'video/x-flv',
    'webm'  =>  'video/webm',
    'aac'   =>  'audio/x-acc',
    'm4u'   =>  'application/vnd.mpegurl',
    'm3u'   =>  'text/plain',
    'xspf'  =>  'application/xspf+xml',
    'vlc'   =>  'application/videolan',
    'wmv'   =>  array('video/x-ms-wmv', 'video/x-ms-asf'),
    'au'    =>  'audio/x-au',
    'ac3'   =>  'audio/ac3',
    'flac'  =>  'audio/x-flac',
    'ogg'   =>  array('audio/ogg', 'video/ogg', 'application/ogg'),
    'kmz'   =>  array('application/vnd.google-earth.kmz', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip'),
    'kml'   =>  array('application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml', 'application/xml', 'text/xml'),
    'ics'   =>  'text/calendar',
    'ical'  =>  'text/calendar',
    'zsh'   =>  'text/x-scriptzsh',
    '7zip'  =>  array('application/x-compressed', 'application/x-zip-compressed', 'application/zip', 'multipart/x-zip'),
    'cdr'   =>  array('application/cdr', 'application/coreldraw', 'application/x-cdr', 'application/x-coreldraw', 'image/cdr', 'image/x-cdr', 'zz-application/zz-winassoc-cdr'),
    'wma'   =>  array('audio/x-ms-wma', 'video/x-ms-asf'),
    'jar'   =>  array('application/java-archive', 'application/x-java-application', 'application/x-jar', 'application/x-compressed'),
    'svg'   =>  array('image/svg+xml', 'application/xml', 'text/xml'),
    'vcf'   =>  'text/x-vcard',
    'srt'   =>  array('text/srt', 'text/plain'),
    'vtt'   =>  array('text/vtt', 'text/plain'),
    'ico'   =>  array('image/x-icon', 'image/x-ico', 'image/vnd.microsoft.icon')
);
```

This is my mime.php what is in codeigniter.

I upload image or pdf, video(mp4) file, it response mime type correct 
but,
in txt file, it response xml

```
$type = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i]);
            echo $type;
```

->application/xml
or any resonpose x-empty

Is there any long of it?
I want any setting of it exactly mime.php to file upload in codeigniter or refer to document. 
If you know about it, please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the content-type of a file in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php)

Comment: Please read the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1232769/how-to-get-the-content-type-of-a-file-in-php).

Comment: @Martin Thanks but I know How I get it in codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

`'tmp_name'` will result `phpF336.tmp` change it to `'name'`

```
$type = mime_content_type($_FILES['file']['name'][$i]);
```

or directy

```
$type = $_FILES['file']['type'][$i];
# image/jpeg
```