# Why doesn't php correctly detect a pdf mime type (wkhtmltopdf)?

Tags: php, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

## The problem.

I created a pdf using wkhtmltopdf and php will not recognize it as a pdf. When I lookup the mime type it returns `unknown`.

How can I either:

- Fix wkhtmltopdf hopefully with a setting
- Adjust php's pdf file recognition algorithm to see it as a pdf.

## Code

PHP version 5.6
Apache 2.4
Windows 10 Pro
fileinfo 1.0.5
wkhtmltopdf "0.12.4 (with patched qt)"

```
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
return $file_info->file($file_path); // returns "/unknown"
```

## To reproduce.

I can't attache a pdf here but simply run the wkhtmltopdf tool per the instructions on the homepage: `wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf` then run the above php code on it.

Comment: I just tried it and I wasn't able to reproduce your error, I got this response `'application/pdf'`

Comment: Can you please 1) show the version of fileinfo extension `echo phpversion('fileinfo');` 2) ensure that file exists at `$file_path`?

Comment: OS and version?

Comment: @IvanKalita Added to my quesiton.

Comment: @mega6382 added some more info. Good to know that it works for you maybe I can tweak something and get it running then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the environment, I ran it on:

**OS:** *Win 10 Pro*

**Apache:** *Apache/2.4.27 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.1.9*

**PHP:** *7.1.9*

**FileInfo:** *1.0.5*

**WkHTMLtoPDF:** *wkhtmltox-0.12.4_msvc2015*

I ran the command on `CMD in Admin mode`:

```
 C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin>wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

And Ran the following PHP code(after moving the `google.pdf` to my dir inside htdocs):

```
$file_path = "google.pdf";
$file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
var_dump($file_info->file($file_path));
```

And the output was(*Successfully*):

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\htmlpdf\test.php:5:string 'application/pdf' (length=15)
```

If this isn't working for you, I would suggest the following methods:

1) Using [`mime_content_type`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mime-content-type.php), said to be <s>`deprecated`</s>

```
$file_path = "google.pdf";
var_dump(mime_content_type($file_path));
```

2) Using [`finfo_open`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php), it is the same as `new finfo` but still, worth a try:

```
$file_path = "google.pdf";
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $file_path);
finfo_close($finfo);
var_dump($mimetype);
```

3) OR if you don't mind using external libraries, and fallback dependencies try:

1. http://getid3.sourceforge.net/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3664655

Comment: ah php 7. I can't change php versions at the moment due to some dependencies I can't control. But everything else appears the same.

Comment: Seems deprecated function does the job. It will work until I can upgrade php.