# How to add multiple mime types in php for google drive api

Tags: php, google-drive-api, mime-types

I have used google drive api to upload files. Here in the code of file upload, a mime type is mentioned.

```
$result = $service->files->create(
        $file,
        array(
            'data' => file_get_contents($file_path),
            'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        )
    );
```

i want the mime-type to be pdf and doc/docx, how can I make this happen?

Comment: You want one file to have multiple mime types?

Comment: No the user will upload files so it can be either pdf or doc

Comment: Just use [`mime_content_type`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38476126/231316)